# Converting RGB float data to hex string

Tags: c#, rgb

I'm writing a tool to modify a game, and the game uses float's to store RGB data (ranging from 0.0 -> 1.0). How would you best suggest I go about converting from float RGB Data to a Hex String/Byte RGB Data?

Comment: -1 Zero research effort.

Comment: On the contrary, I just spent 15 minutes googling, but I don't think I was phrasing my searching correctly, and not getting anything relevant.

Comment: http://ideone.com/e2iyPI Here's sample in that case.

Comment: I know how to do that, but sadly that isn't what I was looking todo. Paul below posted the code to do what I needed, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var rgbString = string.Format("#{0}{1}{2}", 
    ((int)(redValue * 255)).ToString("X2"), 
    ((int)(greenValue * 255)).ToString("X2"), 
    ((int)(blueValue * 255)).ToString("X2"));
```

edited (perhaps more readable code):

```
var rgbString = string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", 
    (int)(redValue * 255), 
    (int)(greenValue * 255), 
    (int)(blueValue * 255));
```

Comment: Thanks man, that's exactly what I was looking for. I'll mark it as the correct answer as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 1):

```
float rVal = 0.5f;
float gVal = 0.94140625f;
float bVal = 0.21484375f;

byte rByte = (byte)(rVal * 256);
byte gByte = (byte)(gVal * 256);
byte bByte = (byte)(bVal * 256);

string rgb = rByte.ToString("X2") + gByte.ToString("X2") + bByte.ToString("X2");
```

Result:

> 80F137